# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused in TCP socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have created a program to send file from client to server but when i am running that file in localhost it works good and i can send the file but when i am sending that file from another PC to my PC it shows "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused".

Port number at both side same and firewall is also off. Even port is listening when client request to connect server socket is also accepting the socket.

Thank you in advance

Code of my program is :

```
public class ProgramSocket {

    public ProgramSocket(ServerSocket servsock) throws IOException {

        System.out.print("server started");
        while (true) {
            final Socket sock;
            try {
                sock = servsock.accept();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                break;
            }
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        connectToNewClient(sock);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        System.out.print("server stopped");

    }

    void connectToNewClient(Socket sock) throws IOException,
    InterruptedException {


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/abc.txt");

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
        bos.close();


        sock.close();
    }
}
```

Client side :

```
public String uploadFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    Socket sock = new Socket(ip, 24999);

    // select file
    File myFile = new File(filePath);


    // send the program file
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(myFile));
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os = sock.getOutputStream();
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();
    bis.close();

    sock.close();

    return message;

}
```

omitted some code for brevity.

Comment: The only issue here is whether you're using the correct IP address and port number in the client, and only you know that.

Comment: Most likely, he's using the wrong IP address in the server. Can you show us your evidence that the port is listening?

Comment: I am using correct ip to connect with other PC and connection is also established but when I am trying to send the file it shows me connection refuse

Comment: And you can absolutely confirm that any software inbound firewall is off on the server, and any software outbound firewall is off on the client, and there is no firewall of any type between them?

Comment: I have already closed the firewall at both side @JasonC

Comment: What line is causing the "Connection Refused" error? And are you seeing any exceptions on the server side? What about that `SocketException` you're silently handling up at `servsock.accept()`, is that getting thrown?

Comment: @SmitShilu Make up your mind. The statements "connection is also established but when I am trying to send the file it shows me connection refuse" are mutually contradictory. How are you constructing your `ServerSocket?`